# Why TimeSpan.ToString() returns wrong minutes presentation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, timespan

I use `System.TimeSpan` a lot in my program to store time intervals. Sometimes I get them from `Stopwatch.Elapsed`, sometimes calculate like `TimeSpan += ...`.

At some point I write these times into log files in two formats:

```
var timeSpan = GetSuperTimeSpan();
logger.Info($"Super Time: {timeSpan}");
logger.Info($"Super Time (ms): {(long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}");
```

The first string used when log files are read by humans. The second one is used by automation. Usually it works fine, but *sometimes* I observe such log entries:

```
Super Time: 00:02:27.4860547
Super Time (ms): 207486
```

If you take a look at these numbers closely you can notice that `207486` actually should be 0**3**:27 instead of 0**2**:27. And I see multiple errors like that in logs and everytime it is exactly **minus one minute**.

It happens not always, so I see in the same log file correct presentations and wrong ones in random order. I run my program under .net 6 runtime on windows 11 machines.

Does anyone has a clue what is going on and how it is possible? For me it sounds like a pure magic for several days already =)

Comment: i can't replicate that - include a minimal piece of code that we can run that demonstrates this

Comment: Do u use threads? Multiple servers? ... we need a better understanding of the context. Maybe a short example can help us to understand better the situation.

Comment: The code as simple as an example above. I can not replicate this in simple apps also. `TimeSpan` is a struct so when I take it and call .ToString all other threads can not change it...

Comment: With the code you are showing us the only logical conclusion can be that either `TimeSpan.ToString()` or `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` has a bug which is extremely unlikely. The issue probably is in some other part of your code.

Comment: In which part for example? logger just writes strings in a text file. timeSpan is a struct and it has correct amount of milliseconds. I think probably current thread culture can affect that or things like that..